# Am I missing an escape for one of these quotes?

Tags: php, wordpress, quotes

I'm not entirely sure why this isn't working. But this piece of code does not work.

```
<?php
foreach ( $gallery_ids as $gallery ) {
    echo '<div class="tgallery" rel="'.$gallery['gid'].'"><?php echo do_shortcode("[nggallery id='.$gallery['gid'].']"); ?></div>';
}
?>
```

I was guessing that maybe I'm putting the wrong quotes in the wrong place.

All the parts seperately work, as in :

1. I can display the `'gid'` value with `echo $gallery['gid']`
2. I can make the div tags appear with the appropriate `rel`
3. I can, by itself, make `<?php echo do_shortcode("[nggallery id=3]"); ?>` work.

I just can't make the entire thing appear together.

Comment: what's the point in placing `<?PHP` tags inside of `echo` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you put `<?php  ?>` inside your echo ?

```
<?php
foreach ( $gallery_ids as $gallery ) 
{
    echo '<div class="tgallery" rel="'.$gallery['gid'].'">'.do_shortcode('[nggallery id='.$gallery['gid'].']').'</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing interpolated php and html, placing `"<?php echo"` inside what's already php.

```
<div class="tgallery" rel="<?php echo $gallery['gid'];?>">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id="'.$gallery['gid'].'"]'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### The issue

Pick either string concatenation or opening/closing PHP for HTML. You cannot combine both as you have done above.

```
echo '<div class="tgallery" rel="'.$gallery['gid'].'">
         <?php echo do_shortcode("[nggallery id='.$gallery['gid'].']"); ?>
      </div>';
```

The second line of code above does not belong inside a string as code in between the `<?php ... ?>` will not be parsed by PHP when it is contained in a string.

### Solutions

#### Concatenation

I have fixed your code to use concatenation below:

```
foreach ( $gallery_ids as $gallery ) {
    $shortcode = do_shortcode("[nggallery id={$gallery['gid']}]");
    echo '<div class="tgallery" rel="' . $gallery['gid'] . '">' . $shortcode . '</div>';
}
```

#### Opening and closing PHP

This is how you would do it using PHP "templating":

```
<?php foreach($gallery_ids as $gallery ): ?>
    <div class="tgallery" rel="<?php echo $gallery['gid']; ?>">
        <?php echo do_shortcode("[nggallery id={$gallery['gid']}]"); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already "in" php, so your opening tag is causing the problem:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[nggallery id='.$gallery['gid'].']"); ?>
```

It should be something like:

```
echo '<div class="tgallery" rel="'.$gallery['gid'].'">' . do_shortcode('[nggallery id='.$gallery['gid'].']') . '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
foreach ( $gallery_ids as $gallery ) { 
    echo "<div class=\"tgallery\" rel=\"{$gallery["gid"]}\">". do_shortcode("[nggallery id=\"{$gallery["gid"]}\"]") ."</div>";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
<?php
foreach ( $gallery_ids as $gallery ) {
    echo '<div class="tgallery" rel="'.$gallery['gid'].'">'.do_shortcode("[nggallery id=".$gallery['gid']."]").'</div>';
}
?>
```

you have  inside a php statment

Try [Notepad](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v5.9.8.html) then it will colour code your php code, so you can clearly see what quotes etc you have wrong